# Status bar style for one view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I have set my status bar style to light for my project and it work like charm, but i need to change the style to black for one viewController I'm using this : 
In my viewDidLoad method, I call:
     `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]` 
and set :

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle { 
       return UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent; }
```

But my status bar still light.

Comment: Is the key "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to YES in your plist? That's its default value if you haven't changed it.

Comment: Yes i already add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in the specific viewContrller you want the status bar normal

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle { 
   return UIStatusBarStyleDefault; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds as if you forgot to set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in your info plist.